# React Native - Release crash after login (Debug work)

Tags: react-native, keychain

I have been looking into some issues related to mine, but i can't find the right answer, it works when i use the debug version but when i try to use the release i got a problem when i use Keychain.setGenericPassword , i'm quite sure the problem is when login is valid i try to store the data:

```
if ( responseData.success )
{
    Keychain.setGenericPassword(this.state.username, this.state.password);
    GLOBAL.API_KEY = responseData.api_key;
    ( responseData.setupAccount ? Actions.conta() : Actions.home() );
}
```

I did the **adb logcat** command  to see the exceptions and i got this:

> W/dalvikvm( 2935): **Pending exception is**: I/dalvikvm( 2935):
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: **no field with name='mCtxPtr' signature='J'**
>   in class L**com/facebook/crypto/cipher/NativeGCMCipher**; I/dalvikvm(
>   2935):      at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method) I/dalvikvm(
>   2935):      at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:368)
>   I/dalvikvm( 2935):      at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535) I/dalvikvm( 2935):
>   at
>   com.facebook.crypto.util.SystemNativeCryptoLibrary.loadLibraries(SystemNativeCryptoLibrary.java:50)
>   I/dalvikvm( 2935):      at
>   com.facebook.crypto.util.SystemNativeCryptoLibrary.ensureCryptoLoaded(SystemNativeCryptoLibrary.java:39)
>   I/dalvikvm( 2935):      at
>   com.facebook.crypto.Crypto.isAvailable(Crypto.java:54) I/dalvikvm(
>   2935):      at
>   com.oblador.**keychain.KeychainModule.setGenericPasswordForOptions**(KeychainModule.java:48)
>   I/dalvikvm( 2935):      at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) I/dalvikvm(
>   2935):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   I/dalvikvm( 2935):      at
>   com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:363)
>   I/dalvikvm( 2935):      at
>   com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:166)
>   I/dalvikvm( 2935):      at
>   com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
>   I/dalvikvm( 2935):      at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) I/dalvikvm( 2935):
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

Can anyone give me some tips, what am i doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got helped on github, and i forgot to add:

```
-keep class com.facebook.crypto.** {
   *;
}
```

in **proguard-rules.pro** file ( https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain/blob/master/README.md#proguard-rules )

And i did one more change in the code because KeyChain is actually return a Promise, so my code is now:

```
Keychain.setGenericPassword(username, password).then(function() {
    console.log('Credentials saved successfully!');
});
```

All credits go to **malonguwa** (https://github.com/malonguwa), the user that helped me on github.

Comment: I am getting same issue when I try to installed signed app on android 7.0 device. I have set progruard rules too. If any help.